# CRA with manual proxy config not sending the correct cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

I have a create react app dev server running on `http://localhost:3000`. This dev server needs to fetch data from a remote server on a different domain `https://mydomain.in`. To achieve this I have the below proxy config in `setupProxy.js` file -

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const CLOUD_URL = 'https://mydomain.in';

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: CLOUD_URL,
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false,
            ws: true,
            cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost',
            logLevel: 'debug'
        })
    );
};
```

The requests are being proxied but cookie being sent is not the target's cookie. The response of all the requests is the login page of my remote server. Please suggest if I am missing something. Thank you so much in advance!

Note - I have logged-in to my application in different tab on the same browser as the dev server. The remote server has CORS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> I have logged-in to my application in different tab on the same browser as the dev server. The remote server has CORS enabled.

In order for the cookie rewriting to work properly, you need to have the cookie present on `localhost`. You can use an extension like [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) to configure it.

Once you have the cookie on `localhost` the `cookieDomainRewrite` should begin working and your request should no longer be hitting the login page.